# Some users reporting site not secure

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a client who just installed an SSL certificate. I added this to the .htaccess file to force users to redirect to https and force them to www:

```
# Redirect bare domain to www and HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.twentyteninc.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I also addressed all the mixed content warnings. Now, everything redirects to https and I get the beautiful lock symbol in all browsers I test with.

Unfortunately, though, some users are still seeing the "Not Secure" messages:

[image: ssl error]

If I run a Qualys SSL Test, it comes back with an A score:

[image: Qualys Test]

What could be causing this? Why does everything look secure for me but not for some?

Comment: "Why does everything look secure for me but not for some?" Depending on what you have in your trust store or if some visitors are behind some proxy that intercept HTTPS communication and deliver other certificates instead. Did they test with other browsers too?

Comment: Ask the visitors that have the problem to show exactly which certificate they get from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the WordPress theme the client is using was pulling the favicon over HTTP instead of HTTPS and for whatever reason, my browser (and all the other browsers I tested with) was simply choosing not to load it at all.

This caused me never to get a mixed content warning.

After staring at the screenshot above for long enough, I noticed that the favicon was loading and that it wasn't for me which tipped me off to go digging through the theme for it.